# JFrame action listener - Erron

Tags: java

I have create a Java application using xcode. In that application i am getting the error in the following declaration -

Public class testapp extends JFrame implements ActionListener{}

the error is - 
"testapp is not abstract & does not override abstract method actionPerformed (java.awt.event_ActionEvents) in java.awt.events_ActionListener"

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the methods defined by the interface. Paste:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
}
```

into your code.

Answer (score 0):

Classes that implement an interface must implement the methods defined by it. In your case you must implement the actionPerformed method in your class.